# Maven fails to scan dependency

Tags: maven, batik

I have a dependency added as an aggregate into my pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
    <artifactId>batik-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.14</version>
</dependency>
```

Complilation runs fine without any issues, but during startup there are multiple issues, which can be grouped into two groups:

- Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: D:.m2\repository\org\apache\xmlgraphics\batik-ttf2svg\1.14\lib\batik-ttf2svg-1.14.jar

  There is no 'lib' folder in the real path
- Failed to scan [file:/D:/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlgraphics/batik-ttf2svg/1.14/lib/batik-constants-1.14.jar] from classloader hierarchy (main)

  App tries to scan a different jar from the artifact folder. My guess is that this 'wrong' artifact is a dependency, which is looked up in the incorrect folder.

I tried injecting dependencies directly with aggregate jar, but overall the errors are the same. The whole project setup is quite complicated, there might be some configuration that messes this up, but I cannot find it.

What can be the reason behind it and what is the possible fix?

Thanks!

Comment: I tried running the same dependency in the fresh project - and there is no issue, which confirms some mess in my initial project.

Comment: What do you mean by `added as an aggregate into my pom`? Adding a dependency means it. will become part of the classpath. Where does the path `lib` coming from? Have you configured that somewhere? Please show the code.. ? Please show the whole setup or even better a link to github or alike?

Answer (score 0):

1. This path could be hard coded in your project, find and remove

```
D:.m2\repository\org\apache\xmlgraphics\batik-ttf2svg\1.14\lib\batik-ttf2svg-1.14.jar
```

2. try to rename or delete xmlgraphics folder so than maven can download the dependencies once again, then clean and build your project

```
 mvn clean install
```

Comment: nope, nothing is hardcoded - that's a freshly added dependency. Perhaps it's added somewhere in the dependency pom's, but I was not able to find it + it's out of my control anyway.
I also tried cleaning/installing, tried redownloading dependency, tried different version - the error is pretty much the same.